# Maximum number of retries using DecorrelatedJitterBackoff

Tags: c#, polly, retry-logic, exponential-backoff, resiliency

I am using polly DecorrelatedJitterBackoff policy for retrying the http request. My use case is some thing like when the timeSpan reaches 300 seconds it should retry int.maximum number of times for every 300 seconds.

I am trying to achieve this using the following code. I used int.MaxValue which gave out of range exception so i am using 2100000000. The code works but takes too much of time to execute.Please suggest an efficient way to achieve this?

```
    private static readonly List<int> ExceptionCodes = new List<int> { 408, 429, 500, 503, 504, 520 };
    var delay = Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(medianFirstRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2500), 10);

    var decorrelatedJitterDelay = this.GetTimeSpanList(delay.ToArray());

    this.RetryPolicy = Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => ExceptionCodes.Contains((int)r.StatusCode))
     .WaitAndRetryAsync(decorrelatedJitterDelay);

     var policyResult = this.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(() => this.RequestServer(equipmentId));



     private IEnumerable<TimeSpan> GetTimeSpanList(TimeSpan[] delay)
            {
                var index = 0;
                var timeSpanList = new List<TimeSpan>();
                foreach (var time in delay)
                {
                    if (time > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300))
                    {
                       var timeDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
                       delay[index] = timeDelay;
                       timeSpanList.Add(delay[index]);
                    }

                    index++;
                }

               // 2100000000  is the maximum capacity of List<>.
                for (int i = index; i < 2100000000 - index; i++)
                {
                    timeSpanList.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300));
                }

                return timeSpanList;
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several tiny things that needs to be modified in order to achieve the desired behaviour.

### `sleepDurationProvider`

If you look at the definition of the `sleepDurationProvider` parameter of the `WaitAndRetry` method then you can see it is a function which will produce a timeSpan based on some input like current retry count, context, etc..

```cs
Func<int, TimeSpan>
Func<int, DelegateResult<HttpResponseMessage>, Context, TimeSpan>
...
```

So, instead of specifying each sleep duration in advance we can calculate them on demand. This is really good because we can take advantage of `yield return` to create a new TimeSpan on demand by putting into account the previous ones.

Here is a sample method, which will generate TimeSpans on demand:

```cs
private static IEnumerable<TimeSpan> GetDelay()
{
    TimeSpan fiveMinutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    var initialBackOff =  Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(medianFirstRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2500), 10);
    foreach (var delay in initialBackOff.Where(time => time < fiveMinutes))
    {
        yield return delay;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        yield return fiveMinutes;
    }
}
```

- We generate the first 10 duration with the `DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2`.
- We filter out those that are greater than 5 minutes (`Where(time => time < fiveMinutes)`)
- After the retry policy exhausted the initial backoffs the we will always return with 5 minutes.
- Please note that this Iterator never returns.

  - But because it is consumed on demand that's why it is not a big problem.

Let's test this method by querying the first 20 sleep durations:

```cs
foreach (var ts in GetDelay().Take(20))
{
    Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalSeconds);
}
```

The output will be:

```
0.5985231
4.0582524
5.1969925
15.4724158
16.4869722
15.8198397
75.7497326
118.5080045
272.2401684
300
300
300
300
300
300
300
300
300
300
300
```

### `WaitAndRetry` vs `WaitAndRetryForever`

Even though the former does have several overloads which accepts an `IEnumerable<TimeSpan>` parameter I would not recommend it. Most of the overloads require an explicit `retryCount` and that's why in most people mind this function is considered a predefined, finite retry executor.

I do suggest to use `WaitAndRetryForever` because it expresses the intent. Without the need to look at the sleep duration generator it is obvious what do we want.

Here is the refined `RetryPolicy` definition:

```cs
var sleepDurations = GetDelay().GetEnumerator();
var retryPolicy = Policy
    .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => ExceptionCodes.Contains((int)r.StatusCode))
    .WaitAndRetryForever(retry =>
    {
        sleepDurations.MoveNext();
        return sleepDurations.Current;
    });
```

- `WaitAndRetryForever` does not have any overload which accepts `IEnumerable<TimeSpan>` that's why we have to use some boilerplate code.
- `sleepDurations` is an iterator and each time when the retry policy needs to calculate the sleep duration we move that forward.
- This algorithm does not put into account the current retry count (`retry`) so you could use the discards there if you wish (`.WaitAndRetryForever(_ => ...`)

### `Execute` vs `ExecuteAsync` vs `ExecuteCapture` vs ...

Depending on how do you specify your policy you can call `Execute` or `ExecuteAsync`. The former is for sync operations and the latter one is for async I/O operations.

```cs
RetryPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> retryPolicy = Policy.....WaitAndRetryForever(...
retryPolicy.Execute(() => ....);
```

or

```cs
AsyncRetryPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> retryPolicy = Policy.....WaitAndRetryForeverAsync(...
await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await ...)
```

- `ExecuteAsync` anticipates an async function (`Func<Task<...>>`) that's why we have to use `async() => await ...`
- `ExecuteAsync` does return with a `Task` so it should be awaited as well.

If your `RequestServer` is a sync method then use the former if it is async then use the latter.

I also encourage you to use the simple `Execute` instead of `ExecuteAndCapture` if you are not interested about the policy related information just about the result itself.

```cs
var result = retryPolicy.Execute(() => this.RequestServer(equipmentId));
sleepDurations.Dispose();
```