# Polly not catching Nsubstitute's mocked exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, nsubstitute, polly

I am using `Polly`'s retry policy for my unsuccessful call. But it is not catching the exception and retrying.

Using:

- **Polly 7.2.3**
- **.NET6.0**
- **Nsubstitute 4.2.2**

**Setup:**

```
var delay = Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(RetryDelay), RetryCount);

        
_retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<HttpRequestException>()
                     .Or<CustomException>()
                     .OrResult<string>(response => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
                     .WaitAndRetryAsync(delay);
```

**Usage:**

```
public async Task ProcessRequest()
{
    var errors = await _retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await this.RetryProcessRequest());
}

private async Task<string> RetryProcessRequest()
{
    var token = await _tokenInfrastructure.GetTokenAsync();

    return await _timezoneInfrastructure.ProcessRequest(token);
}
```

**Unit test:**

```
[Fact]
public async Task ProcessRequest_Throws()
{
    string errors = _fixture.Create<string>();
    var token = _fixture.Create<string>();

    // Retry policy configured to retry 3 times on failed call 
    var expectedReceivedCalls = 4;

    // this is throwing but Polly is not catching it and not retrying 
    _tokenInfrastructure.GetTokenAsync().Returns(Task.FromException<string>(new HttpRequestException())); 

    // this errors can be caught by Polly as configured and retrying
    _timezoneInfrastructure.ProcessRequest(token).Returns(errors); 

    await _timezoneOrchestration.Awaiting(o => o.ProcessRequest()).Should()
        .ThrowAsync<HttpRequestException>();

    await _tokenInfrastructure.Received(expectedReceivedCalls).GetTokenAsync();
    await _timezoneInfrastructure.Received(expectedReceivedCalls).ProcessRequest(Arg.Any<string>());
}
```

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include the potential fix. Please post an answer instead.

Comment: BTW are you sure that you want to retry when the response is **NOT** `null` or empty string?

Comment: really strange and badly designed but **YES** .  `_timezoneInfrastructure` returns not empty string if something went wrong

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Gotcha on the condition

Comment: If you don't mind I would post tomorrow an answer where I detail several thoughs about your code. There are a couple of things which bothers me

Comment: @PeterCsala of course, would be great!

Answer (score 1):

After doing [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) found my mistake. Actually, Polly was configured well and retrying.

this line of code was never calling because above we were getting exceptions.

```
return await _timezoneInfrastructure.ProcessRequest(token);
```

In Unit tests, it was expecting some retry calls:

```
_timezoneInfrastructure.Received(expectedReceivedCalls).ProcessRequest(Arg.Any<string>());
```

Answer (score 1):

This post is not answer for the OP's question (*the problem has already been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73652642/13268855)*). It is more like a set of suggestions (you can call it *code review* if you wish).

---

#### Exponential backoff

I'm glad to see that you are using the V2 of the backoff logic which utilizes the jitter in a proper way.
My only concern here is that depending on the actual values of `RetryDelay` and  `RetryCount` the `sleepDuration` might explode: It can easily reach several minutes. I would suggest two solutions in that case:

- Change `factor` parameter of the `DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2` from 2 (which is the default) to a lower number
- Or try to top the max `sleepDuration`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60668814/maximum-number-of-retries-using-decorrelatedjitterbackoff) I have detailed one way to do that

#### Combined Retry logic

Without knowing what does `RetryProcessRequest` do, it seems like this `_retryPolicy`  smashes two different policies into one. *I might be wrong, so this section could suggest something which is not applicable for your code.*

I assume this part decorates the `_tokenInfrastructure.GetTokenAsync` call

```
_retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<HttpRequestException>()
                     .WaitAndRetryAsync(delay);
```

whereas this part decorates the `_timezoneInfrastructure.ProcessRequest` call

```
_retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<CustomException>()
                     .OrResult<string>(response => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
                     .WaitAndRetryAsync(delay);
```

Based on your naming I assume that these are different downstream systems: `tokenInfrastructure`, `timezoneInfrastructure`. I would suggest to create separate policies for them. You might want to apply different Timeout for them or use separate Circuit Breakers.

#### Naming

I know naming is hard and I assume your method names (`ProcessRequest`, `RetryProcessRequest` or `ProcessRequest_Throws`) are dumyfied for StackOverflow. If not then please try to spend some time to come up with more expressive names.

#### Component testing

Your `ProcessRequest_Throws` test is not really a unit test. It is more likely a component test. You are testing there the integration between the Polly's policy and the decorated code.

If you would test only **the correctness of the policy setup** or test only **the decorated code** (with [`NoOpPolicy`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Unit-testing-with-Polly#1-i-want-to-unit-test-what-my-code-does-independent-of-polly-policies-i-apply)) then they were unit tests.

Comment: Thank you taking your time and making suggestions! I totally agree with `naming` :). `Combined retry` logic is because, most of the time call is failing because of `token` is expired so I need to retry whole process