# Demystify HTTP timeout and retry with Polly

Tags: c#, .net-core, timeout, dotnet-httpclient, polly

Register services:

```
var host = new HostBuilder().ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddHttpClient<Downloader>(client =>
    {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1); // -- T1
    })
    .AddPolicyHandler(HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .Or<HttpRequestException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), // -- T2
            retryCount: 3)))
    .AddPolicyHandler(Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(10)) // -- T3
    .AddPolicyHandler(HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .CircuitBreakerAsync(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))); // -- T4

    services.AddTransient<Downloader>();

}).Build();
```

The implementation of `Downloader`:

```
class Downloader
{
    private HttpClient _client;
    public Downloader(IHttpClientFactory factory)
    {
        _client = factory.CreateClient();
    }

    public void Download(List<Uri> links)
    {
        await Parallel.ForEachAsync(
            links, 
            async (link, _cancelationToken) =>
            {
                await _client.GetStreamAsync(uri, _cancellationToken);
            });
    }
}
```

In this pseudocode, I'm confused about the correlation between the timeouts, and how/when an HTTP request will be resubmitted. Specifically:

- How `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, and `T4` are "orchestrated"? I am assuming if the endpoint does not respond in `T1`, `await _client.GetStreamAsync` throws timeout exception, then in intervals related to `T2`, the HTTP request will be submitted for max `3` times, or if the circuit breaker timer reaches `T4`. Then what is the role of `T3`?
- Is all the configuration related to the client and `HttpMessageHandler`, and I still need to wrap the call to `GetStreamAsync` as the following?!

```
Policy
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .RetryAsync(3)
    .ExecuteAsync(
        async () => await _client.GetStreamAsync(uri, _cancellationToken));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First let me provide some suggests and then discuss your questions.

### Prefer `Wrap` over multiple `AddPolicyHandler`s

The `AddPolicyHandler` registers a `PolicyHttpMessageHandler` which is a `DelegatingHandler`. In your case you have 3 `DelegatingHandler`s so the exception propagation is done by the ASP.NET Core instead of Polly.

If you would prefer `Policy.WrapAsync` then you could chain the policies in a Polly way ([escalation](https://github.com/peter-csala/resilience-service-design/blob/main/resilience.md#esc)).

```
var T2 = HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .Or<HttpRequestException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
            retryCount: 3));

var T3 = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(10);

var T4 = HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .CircuitBreakerAsync(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

```
var resilienceStrategy = Policy.WrapAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(T2, T3, T4);
var host = new HostBuilder().ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services
      .AddHttpClient<Downloader>(client =>
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
      .AddPolicyHandler(resilienceStrategy);

    services.AddTransient<Downloader>();

}).Build();
```

### Further suggestions

#### Swapping Timeout and Circuit Breaker

By the way it might make sense to swap the Timeout and the CircuitBreaker policies. If the Timeout would be the most inner and you would adjust the Circuit Breaker policy to be aware of timeout problems (`.Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()`) then it could break for that as well.

```
var T3 = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(10);

var T4 = HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
        .CircuitBreakerAsync(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

var resilienceStrategy = Policy.WrapAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(T2, T4, T3);
```

#### Retry in more cases

It might make sense to perform retry in case of timeout or broken circuit as well

```
var T2 = HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .Or<HttpRequestException>()
        .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
        .Or<BrokenCircuitException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
            retryCount: 3));
```

---

#### Reply to question #2

Please allow me to start with your second question.

> Is all the configuration related to the client and HttpMessageHandler, and I still need to wrap the call to `GetStreamAsync` as the following?!

No, you don't need to do that. Since you have decorated your `HttpClient` with your resilience policies that's why you don't need to do the same for each `HttpClient`'s method call.

#### Reply to question #1

Please allow me to separate this into multiple questions

> How T1, T2, T3, and T4 are "orchestrated"?

- T1 (`HttpClient`'s `Timeout`) acts a global timeout. This means if you need to perform several retries then they will be cancelled after 1 second. So, this is an overarching time constraint for all of the attempts.

  - If Timeout expires then it will [throw a `TaskCancelledException` with an inner `TimeoutException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547895/how-can-i-tell-when-httpclient-has-timed-out)
- T2 (Retry's backoff's `medianFirstRetryDelay`) provides the sleep duration sequence between retries in an exponential backoff manner with jitter. In other words rather than waiting always the same amount of time between each retry attempt it waits every time more and more.

  - If you are interested about the generated sleep durations then [you can iterate through them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60668814/maximum-number-of-retries-using-decorrelatedjitterbackoff)
- T3 (Timeout) acts a local timeout. In other words this timeout is rested and enforced for each and every retry attempt

  - This is the contrast of `HttpClient`'s `Timeout` which is a global timeout
  - If you define a timeout policy as the most outer policy (the left-most parameter of `Policy.WrapAsync`) then it also acts as global
- T4 (Circuit Breaker's `breakDuration`) acts as a gatekeeper. If the CB breaks (in your case after 5 successive failures) then it transitions itself into *Open* state.

  - Any request is terminated with a `BrokenCircuitException` while the CB is *Open*
  - After the `breakDuration` elapsed then it transitions into *HalfOpen* state and allows a single probe. If it succeeds then CB moves back to *Closed* state otherwise to *Open*

> I am assuming if the endpoint does not respond in T1, await _client.GetStreamAsync throws timeout exception, then in intervals related to T2, the HTTP request will be submitted for max 3 times, or if the circuit breaker timer reaches T4. Then what is the role of T3?

With the previous point I think I've addressed this question :). Because you have set the global timeout to 1 seconds that's why your local timeout (10 seconds) will never fire.

If you would set a higher value for your global timeout then the per request (retry attempt based) timeout could fire.

---

If any of the above points is unclear please let me know and I will link some of my earlier post which discuss that in great detail.

---

**UPDATE #1**

> Could you please elaborate a bit more on T1 vs T3?

In the following SO topics I try to make it clear what is the difference between global and local timeouts:

- [Using exponential backoff in Polly Library with httpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62913614/using-exponential-backoff-in-polly-library-with-httpclient/62918314#62918314)
- [Cannot make Polly Timeout Policy override the HttpClient default timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473924/cannot-make-polly-timeout-policy-override-the-httpclient-default-timeout/63563229#63563229)
- [HttpClient Polly WaitAndRetry policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62806212/httpclient-polly-waitandretry-policy/62832357#62832357)

And finally [here is an SO topic which covers how to have longer Timeout than the HttpClient's Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72988521/polly-retries-doesnt-close-existing-httpclient-call).

> Should I implement the logic of catching CB's Open, HalfOpen and Closed states and buffering and holding requests w.r.t. the state, or CB internally buffers and resubmits requests when appropriate?

Circuit Breaker does not work like that. Circuit Breaker does not maintain something like a request queue. It is just a proxy, which can short cut the execution of requests if the downstream system is treated as temporarily unavailable. The CB itself is not performing any retry logic.

The [Rate limiter policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Rate-Limit) also works in the same way. It does not hold the requests until there is enough throughput.

What you can do is to create a CB aware retry logic and combine them

- either by [fine-tuning the parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64866470/polly-circuitbreakerasync-is-not-working-as-i-expect/64871939#64871939)
- or by [passing state transition information from CB to Retry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69534878/unexpected-behaviour-using-nested-retry-and-circuit-breaker-policies-of-polly-n/69551471#69551471)
- or by [using Retry-After header if available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73024445/polly-contrib-waitandretry-to-funnel-all-requests-when-hitting-rate-limit/73055228#73055228)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! it is very insightful. Two clarifying questions: (1) could you please elaborate a bit more on `T1` vs `T3`? (2) Should I implement the logic of catching CB's _Open_, _HalfOpen_ and _Closed_ states and buffering and holding requests w.r.t. the state, or CB internally buffers and resubmits requests when appropriate?

Comment: @Dr.Strangelove I've addressed your questions in my post. Please revisit it.

Comment: That all makes the most sense, thank you for clarifying them.

Comment: Good point! :) thanks.